# How to set time zone to frecnh zone + windows ce

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact, compact-framework2.0

I need to set my timezone in my mobile device to french zone in c# (windows embedded ce)

how can I do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the TimeZone to a city/location, you can only set the DST data.

See my post here: http://community.intermec.com/t5/Device-Management/change-Time-Zone-with-xml/m-p/17007/highlight/true#M1023

============================================================
You can not set the name of a TimeZone using the registry!

You only can set the Offset and DST values. The clock panel then uses a matching entry.

In the registry, the values for "GMT-7 (Mountain US)" and "GMT-7 (Arizona)" are nearly the same

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Clock]
"AppInfo"=hex(3):01,00,00,00,80,01,00,00,0f,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,3a,01,00,00,69,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"AppState"=hex(3):11
"AutoDST"=dword:00000000
"GMT_OFFSET"=dword:000001A4
"HomeDST"=dword:00000000
"NetworkTimeNotifyUser"=dword:00000001
"NetworkTimeSync"=dword:00000001
"TZIndex"=dword:00000004

(see also http://peterfoot.net/HomeAndVisitingClocksInProfessionalEdition.aspx)

and

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Clock]
"AppInfo"=hex(3):01,00,00,00,80,01,00,00,0a,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,3a,01,00,00,69,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"AppState"=hex(3):11
"AutoDST"=dword:00000000
"GMT_OFFSET"=dword:000001A4
"HomeDST"=dword:00000001
"NetworkTimeNotifyUser"=dword:00000001
"NetworkTimeSync"=dword:00000001
"TZIndex"=dword:00000004

But, as you can see, there is no Name String of the time zone.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time]
"TimeZoneInformation"=hex(3):a4,01,00,00,55,00,53,00,20,00,4d,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,61,00,72,00,64,00,20,00,54,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,55,00,53,00,20,00,4d,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,44,00,61,00,79,00,6c,00,69,00,67,00,68,00,74,00,20,00,54,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff

and

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time]
"TimeZoneInformation"=hex(3):a4,01,00,00,4d,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,61,00,72,00,64,00,20,00,54,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0b,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,4d,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,44,00,61,00,79,00,6c,00,69,00,67,00,68,00,74,00,20,00,54,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff

These are the TimeZoneInformations (the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure).

Clipboard02.gif

You may query the timezone city db as done in the attached file (TZ-cities.txt).

The attached tool (timezoneset.exe) can be used to change the offset of the current active timezone.

The time zone informations for Prague and Berlin are the same:

index: 95
    short name: GMT+1 Prague,Budapest
    name: Central Europe Standard Time
    GMT offset: -60
    dst name: Central Europe Daylight Time
    DST offset: 0
...

index: 110
    short name: GMT+1 Berlin,Rome
    name: W. Europe Standard Time
    GMT offset: -60
    dst name: W. Europe Daylight Time
    DST offset: 0

except for the dst name.

It is no good idea to set timezone informations using the registry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to ease your development: https://opennetcf.codeplex.com/

I'm using it and setting the time zone through the following objects: TimeZoneCollection, TimeZoneInformation, DateTimeHelper.